# ER diagram to relational predicate

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, relational-algebra

Can anyone point to the right direction for reference about converting ER digram to relational schema using relational predicate? I looked online and found some. But they are so abstract and do no include any examples at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mapping rule, maybe this can help you.

Rules: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/er_model_to_relational_model.htm